# Selenium->Java->Eclipse: can not be resolved to a type error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm starting to use Eclipse for Selenium automation using Java.
Have installed latest versions of all:
openjdk-15
eclipse-int-win64
selenium-java-3.141.59
chromedriver_win32

Attached my Test program and the corresponding jar files added (obtained from selenium-java language binding 3.141.59).
Are there any other jar files to be added or anything else to be done?
Please help.[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea9xm.png)

Comment: Java 15 requires [Java 15 Support for Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-15-support-eclipse-2020-09-417) to be installed. It seems you have a `module-info.java` file. Delete this file. If this does not help, show the `src` folder expanded and also expand the `Referenced Libraries` node to show the imported classes.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to downgrade java version to 8 that will solve your problem.
[image]

Comment: May i know why that is? Uninstalling and reinstall of Java takes lot of time and effort. I'm ready to do it, just wanted to make sure. Please advise.

Comment: To be true I don't know the exact reason, but when I started with the selenium I was stuck with the same problems(version compatibility). Then somebody told me to use java 8 at that time I was not sure but it worked for me. I know it will be very difficult to reinstall it but I hope this will work for you too.  Please check other things like environment variable, chrome driver as well.

Comment: I moved the JARs from Modulepath to Classpath, then it worked. Tried it with java 14. Thanks for your reply.